Sufficient Statistic for Truncated Normal
I am doing exercise 3.18 of "The Bayesian Choice":

Give a sufficient statistic associated with a sample $x_1,...,x_n$
from a truncated normal distribution  $$ f (x|\theta) \propto \exp(-(x
 - \theta)^2)/2)  \mathbb I[\theta - c,\theta+c](x) $$ when $c$ is known.

Using the factorization criterion I found that the following statistics are sufficient for $\theta$.
$$
T_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i , \quad T_2 = \{x_{(1)} + c , x_{(n)} -c \}
$$
I would like to confirm if the statistics are sufficient, especially for $T_2$. Suppose $T^* =  x_{(1)} + c $ and $T^{**} = x_{(n)} - c$, would that also be sufficient? greetings.

Your $T_2$ can be treated as two statistics or as one two-dimensional statistic.  Indeed you could have one three-dimensional statistic and (since you know $n$ and $c$) it could be $(\bar x, x_{(1)}, x_{(n)})$

I confirm @Henry's point that the sufficient statistic is of dimension $3$ when $n\ge 3$.
